# How to write __init__ method inheriting two classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I have 3 class in my program. `Base`, `Sub_1` and `Sub2`. `Sub_1` inherits from `Base` and `Sub_2` inherits from `QThread` and `Base`.

`Base` class has some `pyQtSignal` properties which I want other two classes to have. Now I have problem instantiating class `Sub_2`. When I run this code I get the following error:

```
QObject::connect: No such signal Sub_2::signal_1()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 31, in <module>
    win = MainWindow()
  File "main.py", line 25, in __init__
    self.worker.signal_1.connect(lambda: print('ok 1'))
TypeError: connect() failed between Base.signal_1[] and unislot()
```

main.py:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, pyqtSignal, QThread

class Base(QObject):
    signal_1 = pyqtSignal()
    signal_2 = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(QObject, self).__init__()


class Sub_1(Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

class Sub_2(QThread, Base):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.worker = Sub_2()
        self.worker.signal_1.connect(lambda: print('ok 1'))
        self.worker.signal_2.connect(lambda: print('ok 2'))


import sys
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
win = MainWindow()
win.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Please show the stack trace

Comment: @MadPhysicist edited error.

Comment: QThread already inherits from QObject, so a simpler solution is to make `Base` inherit from the basic `object`, and eventually make `Sub_1` (and any other class that doesn't inherit from QObject) to actually inherit from `QObject *and* `Base` .

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that `QThread.__init__` properly supports multiple inheritance. The call to `super().__init__()` in `Sub2` may therefore not initialize `Base` as you expect. You can fix this by changing your MRO.

To change the MRO:

```
class Sub_2(Base, QThread):
```

You might want to change `Base` to be more explicit in its support of multiple inheritance. Instead of `super(QObject, self).__init__()`, write

```
super().__init__()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In this code, this fixed the problem but I don't know what is wrong with my main code. code just terminates without any error!

Comment: I dunno. You don't have much of a gui, but the window should show up. Try adding a label to see what happens

Comment: Just to note, `QObject` has to support `super` correctly as well.

Comment: Please have a look at my code. I edited it. I don't know why it doesn't give any error but after starting the thread program terminates. In this code example it gives the error: `AttributeError: 'Sub_2' object has no attribute 'start'`

Comment: QThread already inherits from QObject.

Comment: @Mohammad. I reverted your question, since it now invalidates my answer. Please ask a separate question if you have a separate issue. This is a Q&A site, not a discussion forum.